# Is there a way to wrap an HTML Element inside an Option Tag?

Tags: html, reactjs, icons, tailwind-css, html-select

For example:

```
<select {...props}>
     <option value='my_option'>
        <div className='flex justify-between items-center'>
            <SomeIcon className='w-4'/>
            <p>My Option</p>
        </div>
    </option>
</select>
```

When I try the above, it just discards the icons and only show text with the default styling
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyU9g.png)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to wrap a HTML element inside an `<option>` tag. As per [the HTML specification for `<option>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-option-element):

> ##### Content model:
>
> If the element has a `label` attribute and a `value` attribute: Nothing.
> If the element has a `label` attribute but no `value` attribute: Text.
> If the element has no `label` attribute and is not a child of a `datalist` element: Text that is not inter-element whitespace.
> If the element has no `label` attribute and is a child of a `datalist` element: Text.

Thus, only text is permitted within `<option>` elements. Anything else is discarded.

Answer (score -1):

You could try using JS and CSS in order to use absolute positioning with CSS and  JS to hide it the content when the menu is closed and show the content when the menu is open. However, this requires a medium understanding of CSS and JS.